# Can someone explain the syntax and meaning of lambda/fat arrow angular function call

Tags: angular

Can some break this down for me and explain the syntax and meaning? I know that the `put$` has the meaning of returning an observable, so it is calling the put in the company service and that it has two arguments, and I know what subscribe means, but I need some help understanding it from there.

If you have a link to a good tutorial that would be great.

```
this.companyService.put$(this.currentId, this.appMenu.currentObject)
                   .subscribe(selectedCompany => {this.appMenu.currentObject = selectedCompany});
```

This is the service:

If you could also explain the syntax of the 'put' call that would also be helpful.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Company } from '../models/company.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {
  private url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = "http://localhost:8080/niche/company";
  }

  getOne$ = (companyId: number): Observable<Company> => this.http.get<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`);
  get$ = (): Observable<Company[]> => this.http.get<Company[]>(this.url);
  post$ = (company: Company): Observable<Company> => this.http.post<Company>(this.url, { company });
  patch$ = (companyId: number, company: Company): Observable<Company> => this.http.patch<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`, { company });
  put$ = (companyId: number, company: Company): Observable<Company> => this.http.put<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`, company );
  delete$ = (companyId: number): Observable<Company> => this.http.delete<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`);
}
```

Comment: its basic rxjs / angular / typescript syntax, you should really start at https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following row means:

```
this.companyService
    .put$(this.currentId, this.appMenu.currentObject)
    .subscribe(selectedCompany => {
        this.appMenu.currentObject = selectedCompany
    });
```

If you like a metaphor:

There is an poem in bank (`database`) and you have you have a copy of the poem in your copybook(`client application, in your case Angular application`).

However, you want to edit some rows of poem in your copybook and poem in the bank.

Then you are calling a bank account officer (`this.companyService`)to put your rows (`.put`) into existed poem(`this.currentId, this.appMenu.currentObject`) and then you are waiting a bank account officer (`.subscribe`) until she/he updates poem in the bank.

UPDATE:

[As Angular doc says:](https://angular.io/guide/http)

> The HttpClient in @angular/common/http offers a simplified client HTTP
>   API for Angular applications that rests on the XMLHttpRequest
>   interface exposed by browsers. Additional benefits of HttpClient
>   include testability features, typed request and response objects,
>   request and response interception, Observable apis, and streamlined
>   error handling.

[As MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

> **XMLHttpRequest** or **XHR** is a javascript API used for communication between the client and the server. Use XMLHttpRequest
>   (XHR) objects to interact with servers. You can retrieve data from a
>   URL without having to do a full page refresh. This enables a Web page
>   to update just part of a page without disrupting what the user is
>   doing. XMLHttpRequest is used heavily in AJAX programming.

Contrary to its name, XHR can be used to recieve JSON, HTML and plain text as well as XML.

And an example of using:

```
// 1. Here we are creating a new XMLHttpRequest object
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 2. Then we set its configuration: request of GET type for the URL /somePage/anotherPage
xhr.open('GET', '/somePage/anotherPage');

// 3. We are sending the request over the network
xhr.send();

// 4. Then this rows will be called after the response is received from the 
// server to the client
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status != 200) { // see what HTTP status of the response is come
        alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
    } else { // show the result
        alert(`Great, got ${xhr.response.length} bytes`); // responseText is the server
    }
};

// Get progress from XMLHttpRequest
xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        alert(`We are received ${event.loaded} of ${event.total} bytes`);
    } else {
        alert(`We are received ${event.loaded} bytes`); // no Content-Length
    }

};

xhr.onerror = function () {
    alert("Request failed");
};
```

So `subscribe` method of `HTTPClient` is `onload` method of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: so how/why does the currentObject get passed to the subscribe()?  I understand the basic concept.  I was hoping for more detail about the mechanics.  Maybe, I need to understand the subscribe() call better?